# Is Hartmanis-Stearns conjecture settled by this article?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, computability, automata-theory, nt.number-theory

The paper

> "On the computational complexity of algebraic numbers: the Hartmanis--Stearns problem revisited"
>   by Boris Adamczewski, Julien Cassaigne, Marion Le Gonidec
>   https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02771

claims in Theorem 2.3: "
An algebraic irrational real number cannot be generated by a one-stack machine, or equivalently, by a determistic push down automaton."

I have read and checked the article, have not found any gap in it, and thus the Hartmanis-Stearns conjecture is closed by the theorem? Since the conjecture is hard to prove, I suspect that I misunderstood the article or some fault in it.

Comment: But the Hartmanis-Stearn conjecture is about computability by a real Turing machine, not just by a (D)PDA. This paper proves a weaker form.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, the name of the conjecture is "Hartmanis-Stearns", not "Hartmanis-Stearn".

Second, the Hartmanis-Stearns conjecture concerns those real numbers computable by a multi-tape Turing machine in *real time*; in other words, the TM must compute the n'th digit in n time.

Third, the result of Adamczewski et al. is only about finite automata and deterministic pushdown automata, both of which are weaker models than real-time Turing machines.

Comment: Thank you for your correcting, but could you be so kind as to see https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/why-the-hartmanis-stearns-conjecture-is-still-open/

Comment: I will edit the name of the conjecture. Thank you again

Comment: Nothing Lipton said invalidates my reply.